# How to change Navigation Bar back to translucent after making it transparent

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a view controller in my navigation stack that needs to have a transparent navigation bar, while still showing the back button.

I'm able to achieve that with one line of code inside `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

However, when I try to go back to the previous view, I'm setting the background image back to `nil` or `.none` but I'm losing the translucent effect that was previously on there when I do that.

I've tried setting all the following options in `viewWillDisappear` and none seem to bring the translucency back. It just appears white no matter what I do. The shadow on the bottom is also gone too:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .none
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(.none, for: .default)
```

Initial Navigation Bar:

[image: Initial Navigation Bar]

Transparent Navigation Bar:

[image: Transparent Navigation Bar]

After Transitioning Back:

[image: After Transitioning Back]

Comment: Sorry, don't have rep to comment, so here is a non-answer that adds minor value. I have the same issue, using the same methods for trying to go transparent then back to translucent. The primary thing for readers to note: *It is only an issue when using tall navigation bars*. Setting explicit background images doesn't work, setting them explicitly for each bar metrics value doesn't work. Subclassing UINavigationBar and simply overriding `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` and calling `super()` will even break it. Tall nav bars are incredibly fragile. And since we're transitional from BugReporter to Feedback

Answer (score 1):

In `viewWillAppear` make the navigation bar transparent

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

And backg to translucent in `viewWillDisappear`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Comment: This does the same thing that my original code was doing. It does make the navigation bar translucent when it collapses into the smaller navigation bar but when it is the large style, it does not appear translucent. It just looks like the third screenshot I posted.

Answer (score 0):

After spending time poking around in the UINavigationBar internals, I did discover a simple method that seems to work, and does not require any configuration of the standard UINavigationBar attributes we've previously fiddled with to achieve transparency. The following is tested working on iOS 12.2.x:

```
class TallNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    private lazy var maskingView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: bounds)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }()

    var isTransparent = false {
        didSet {
            guard isTransparent != oldValue, let bkgView = subviews.first else { return }

            bkgView.mask = isTransparent ? maskingView : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, whenever fiddling (even slightly) with undocumented internals: use at your own risk!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my app which needs to revert to an opaque navigation bar after popping from a transparent navigation bar.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = nil
}
```